# socket.io create dynamic room from socket id stored in mysql database

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am having active socket id of each connected user stored in mysql database. I would like to get some selected users from database and then create a room for these selected users and broadcast message to this dynamically created room. Here is my code:

```
var query = pool.query('SELECT socketid FROM registration WHERE sent=1'),
            users = []; // this array will contain the socketid's of connected users stored in our db query
            query
            .on('error', function(err) {
                console.log( err );
            })
            .on('result', function( user ) {
                users.push( user );
            });

            io.emit('refresh feed',status); 
            users.foreach(function(socketid){io.sockets.connected[socketid].join(sendingSocket.id);});
            sendingSocket.to(sendingSocket.id).emit('publicMessage', 'Hello! How are you?');
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to the database takes some time.
But if I am correct, you call the query method asynchronously.
That means, before the users-array is being populated, you already iterate it.
Add a console-output before `io.emit` with the users array.

The solution would be to put the last three lines into the `on('result')`-handler.

Comment: it makes no difference after putting the last three lines into the `on('result')`-handler.  I need to emit/broadcast the message to the users array populated by `SELECT` query. How do i accomplish this.